# Need a Java Regular Expression (regexp) to split a complex CSV file

Tags: java, regex, string, csv

I need to split a CSV file (which I read in as String) containing orders. Parsing rules of this CSV are not that complex:

Each order has several lines (no fix number)

Each order begins with one line (initiator):

```
111;222;dynamic content
```

Each order ends with two lines (terminator):

```
111;333;dynamic content
111;333;dynamic content
```

Initiator and terminator have to be included in the outcome of the split.

[EDIT]
I do not need to use regexp. This was just my first idea. I could also use another solution, if it is easier.
[/EDIT]

I have not much experience with regexp, so even getting started takes a long time :-( 
E.g., I tried the following:

```
String[] parts = body.split("111;333;.*111;333;");
```

Expected result: Splitter is 111;333; to 111;333; - remember, every order ends with two lines, both begin with 111;333; so, String[] should contain the correct number of orders IMO. However, there is only one String in the array which contains everything.

I played around with some other regexps, but I cannot get a good result. Can some one help me and tell me the regular expression for this split? Thanks...

Best regards, 
Kai

Comment: Do you **must** use regex for this? Why not a simple straight String.split() by lines then by field separator? [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/) for an example.

Comment: Not sure you wanna do that with a regular expression. It is gonna be hairy and very hard to maintain. Parse lines using a tokenizer instead.

Comment: I do not have to use regexp! This was just my first idea. An easier solution would be appreciated, of course!

Comment: CSV is the acronym for Comma-Separated Values (or Character-Separated Values) that means that each column of your file is separate by a ';' or another character. You can simply split you row's string using that character and get your data.

Comment: @KaiWähner link I posted in my first comment for an example using String.split()

Comment: @Cirou: Well, of course, you can split it. However, afterwards, you have to implement further processing. So you mean, I should split, and then use "if else logic" etc. to implement a solution?

Comment: @KaiWähner if you don't want to write too much logic than you can use a library like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) but it will not help too much imho

Answer (score 4):

I really would discourage you to try this task using regex. There are many Java libraries for doing this for you. These libraries are tested and very well known. Just take any of them. You will save time and effort. I have good experience using  [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).